# Check for existing markers before adding another

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Google Maps API v2 
Whilst I was waiting for another app to be finalised I was creating another out of interest that would only enable 1 marker to be added to a map at a time (I love maps I do). 
I currently have this code which will clear the map if a marker already exists and then add another one. But what I wanted was for it to show a message telling to user to clear the map before it will allow another marker to be added.

```
@Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng position){
        if (position != null){
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new)));
        }
        else {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new)));           
        }
    }
```

I tried:

```
@Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng position){
        if (position != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clear map before adding another location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new)));           
        }
    }
```

But all that does is show the message I want even when no markers exist so you can't actually add any markers. Should I be utilizing ArrayList here? The app will only allow 1 marker at a time by design. I have looked around and not found anything specific to my needs before asking.

Thanks

This is my edited code, which still doesn't work:

```
@Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng position) {
        mMap.clear();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Position Cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        position = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng position){
        if (position != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clear first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            /*mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new)));*/
        }
        else {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new)));           
        }
    }
```

It is still not letting me add a marker after I have cleared the map using onMapLongClickListener

Answer (score 5, accepted):

addMarker returns a Marker object you can use to update or indicate that you created the Marker already.

You can also use the Marker object to remove it from the map instead of clear() that removes all markers.

in pseudo code:

```
Marker marker;

if(marker == null) {
   marker = map.addMarker(...)
} else {
   ....
}
```

Comment: I will try the marker object update first - as I don't want users to be able accidentally remove their first marker by tapping the map when all they wanted to do was move the map around (found that out by asking a heavy handed basic user to try it)

Comment: Just implemented that code, which works at first, but if you then clear the map you cannot add another marker as you get the Toast message

Comment: when you clear the map don't forget to set the marker to null.

Comment: Yep, thanks I figured that's what I missed out. All working. Hopefully your answer has been marked as correct. Thanks

Comment: Raanan - I have added my edited code, because the answer you supplied I couldn't get to work. What do I need to add to the onMapLongClickListener so that I can add a new marker after clearing the old one?

Comment: I'm sorry but your code isn't complete and actually doesn't look like you used my suggestion at all. why are you checking if "position" isn't null? where does position come from? where are you setting position to something other then null... I'm assuming that every time you click

Comment: My apologies, I did use your code, but in the wrong way, and have uploaded an old version by mistake. Your solution does work. Thank you for your help