# Why is my marker not resetting to null?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, markers

I have a map that will only allow 1 marker at a time. But in order to stop that marker being accidentally replaced with another, it needs to be set so that the marker is cleared before another marker can be added. 
I am setting the marker via onMapClick and clearing them via onMapLongClick. As it stands at the moment, the clearing and adding of markers works fine, but I cannot seem to set up the map so that you need to clear the map first. 
I have tried the solution from [check for existing markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957488/check-for-existing-markers-before-adding-another) but it hasn't worked.
Here is my code for the setup, which currently works by clearing existing marker and adding another without the need to clear the original marker first:

```
@Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng position) {
        mMap.clear();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Position Cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        position = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng position){
        if (position != null){
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new)));
        }
        else {
            
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new)));           
        }
    }
```

But I thought it should be something like:

```
@Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng position) {
        mMap.clear();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Position Cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        position = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng position){
        if (position == null){
            //mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new)));
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clear first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        
        }
    }
```

But all that does is give me the Toast message and not be able to add a marker at all even on first load of the map.

Any help would be great

Comment: Why don't you remember marker reference instead of position? `map.addMarker()` returns reference to added marker. Then when you reference is null add new marker and when it's not null ask for clearing map (you can remove marker by calling its `remove()` method.

Comment: @BobanS. - That is what I am trying and failing to achieve :/

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference to the added marker, and remove it before adding it again on a new LatLng position.

```
private Marker marker;

/**
**
some code here
**
**/

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng position) {
    if(marker != null) 
        marker.remove();
    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new)));
}
```

Comment: mansoulx - I don't know if I'm reading your answer correctly, but to me it reads that - If marker is not null remove it and add another is that correct? If so, what I need is that if marker is not null show a message telling user to remove the previous marker first using a long click on the map or add a marker if marker is null

Answer (score 0):

I realised I was using code incorrectly as such I have fixed the issue as thus:

```
public void onMapClick(LatLng position){
        if(marker == null) {
               marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
               .position(position)
               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_new)));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please clear previous position before adding another", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

The app now does as intended. Thank you for your help